# Dynamic Field Values in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to embed a couple of Cognito Forms on my page. Depending on certain conditions when the page loads, I need to be able to dynamically set a few parameters for the form to use.

For example, I would like the form to BCC email a recipient (or recipients) to email addresses I determine at the time of page load. Is this possible? If I could set some hidden fields or something, I think I would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefill forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in a variety of ways.  Prefill is supported both for embedded forms and forms using our public link.  You simply provide JSON to populate the corresponding fields, which is either passed as an option when prefilling or passed as a query string argument or posted when prefilling a public link form.

Please check out our detailed help topic showing how to prefill in both of these cases:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form